# Spring Boot JMS & Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-messaging

Previously everything worked properly. Today I configured Spring Batch together with my Spring Boot application and faced an issue with `application.properties`.

I have following properties encrypted with Jasypt:

```
spring.profiles.active=https
ENVIRONMENT=h2

#aws sqs
aws.sqs.account.access.key=ENC(kjsdh456fgkjhdfsgkjhdfg)
#queue message listener
queue.message.listener.task.executor.threads.number=1
queue.message.listener.task.executor.max.concurrent.consumers=1
```

Now, in order to configure Spring Batch I added

```
ENVIRONMENT=h2
```

to `application.properties` file.

also, I have added `batch-h2.properties` file:

```
# Placeholders batch.* for H2 database:
batch.jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:~/testdb;CIPHER=AES;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
batch.jdbc.user=sa
batch.jdbc.password="sa sa"
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql
batch.business.schema.script=classpath:/business-schema-h2.sql
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.H2SequenceMaxValueIncrementer
batch.database.incrementer.parent=sequenceIncrementerParent
batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler
batch.grid.size=2
batch.jdbc.pool.size=6
batch.verify.cursor.position=true
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
batch.table.prefix=BATCH_
```

and after that I continuously receiving following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'aws.sqs.account.access.key' in string value "${aws.sqs.account.access.key}"
```

`aws.sqs.account.access.key` property now cannot be resolved.

I'm injecting this property into my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SQSConfig {

    @Value("${aws.sqs.account.access.key}")
    private String accessKey;
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using auto-configuration? Did you use PropertPlaceholerConfigurer to read confg file before?

Comment: I only have `@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties") })` annotation in my application. Everything worked properly until I added `ENVIRONMENT=h2` property.

Comment: Yes, I use auto-configuration

Comment: How do you read `batch-h2.properties`?

Comment: I do not read it manually. This is some internal magic from Srping Batch framework.. or Boot. `ENVIRONMENT=h2` is the key.

Comment: what is your Spring Boot version?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: what makes you think that `ENVIRONMENT=h2` is enabling a profile exactly? Where do you read that?

Comment: In the following example https://github.com/dickerpulli/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot

Comment: it was my mistake. I forgot to add @EnableBatchProcessing annotation